# How to make Shift + Numkeys act as in MS Windows from GUI?

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, mate

I'm using full keyboard with numpad (Generic 105-key intl.). I want to configure it in the following manner.

If NumLock LED is on (NumPad) is enabled, I want to make Numkeys working with `<Shift>` as in MS Windows:

- `<Shift+Num7>` will be `<Home>`;
- `<Shift+Num9>` will be `<PgUp>`;
- `<Shift+Num1>` will be `<End>`;
- `<Shift+Num3>` will be `<PgDn>`;
- `<Shift+Num0>` will be `<Ins>`;
- `<Shift+Num.>` will be `<Del>`.

I forgot how this option is called in `mate-keyboard-properties` of my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS MATE.
In previous versions it was located in "Miscellaneous compatibility options" and named "Shift with numeric keypad keys works as in MS Windows"

[image: mate-keyboard-properties in 14.04 LTS]

with Gsettings equivalent located at

```
org.mate.peripherals-keyboard-xkb.kbd options [''compat\tnumpad:microsoft']
```

Could you please help me to set this option in my 16.04 LTS MATE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The option is located in the same dialog menu - `mate-keyboard-properties` → *Layouts* tab → *Options*, but named a bit longer — *"NumLock on: digits, Shift switches to arrow keys, Numlock off: always arrow keys (as in MS Windows)"* (so it is not visible without scrolling):

[image: mate-keyboard-properties on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS MATE]

Notes:
1. What is interesting Arduino IDE 1.8.4 ignores this option (it is some Java-oriented problem).
2. The method above is also suitable for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS MATE.