# Ubuntu shift arrow key to mark text?

Tags: 20.04, keyboard, text-processing

I just installed latest ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS on my dell inspiron as dual boot with windows 10.

I used to mark text with the keyboard using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Pos1</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> on the numeric keypad. (<kbd>NumLock</kbd> off). The <kbd>Shift</kbd> key results in temporary <kbd>NumLock</kbd> off, but does not mark text as expected.

That really makes it frustrating to use any application.
And: I'm completely new to linux. It already took me some hours to set the german keyboard layout. Just now observed the small 'en' in top right where I can switch to 'de' - probably after a lot of questionable steps taken before.

People who describe linux as simple seem to never have seen anything else. Answers in AskUbuntu don't help if they expect too much knowledge.

Comment: *People who describe linux as simple seem to never have seen anything else* Actually people used to a certain way a doing things tends to confuse familiarity with user friendless. People that used Ubuntu only has the same or worse hard time when they start using Windows. And with all this said, rants are really frown upon here.

Comment: What is your desktop environment?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make Shift + Numkeys act as in MS Windows from GUI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1079698/how-to-make-shift-numkeys-act-as-in-ms-windows-from-gui)? for GNOME use GNOME Tweaks - find [similar option there](https://askubuntu.com/a/1222698/66509).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make Shift + Numkeys act as in MS Windows from GUI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1079698/how-to-make-shift-numkeys-act-as-in-ms-windows-from-gui)